# codeigniter database scaffold

Tags: codeigniter

I have a set of codeigniter files, (full application) with me. But i dont have a datadump.

I created an empty database and now I need codeigniter to scaffold the database by creating all the needed tables and columns of them.

my database settings looks like this.

```
$db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
$db['default']['username'] = 'root';
$db['default']['password'] = '';
$db['default']['database'] = 'databasename';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

This is the current output i get when i access the site.

> Error Number: 1146
>
> Table 'databasename.ci_sessions' doesn't exist
>
> INSERT INTO `ci_sessions` (`session_id`, `ip_address`, `user_agent`,
>   `last_activity`, `user_data`) VALUES
>   ('1dc9905a9c9acbd267163bf99793bd30', '127.0.0.1', 'Mozilla/5.0
>   (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_3) AppleWebKit/535.11 (KHTML, like
>   Gecko) Chrome/17.0.963.56 Safari/535.11', 1336613961, '')
>
> Filename: libraries/Session.php
>
> Line Number: 328

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create the session database table manually.

See the "Saving Session Data to a Database" section on the [User Guide](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html)

**Edit:** This is because you have configured it to save session data in the database (`$config['sess_use_database'] = TRUE;`)